# Every iteration calculate row based on iloc[0 : current]

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to calculate the correlation of 2 columns: price and value.

For every date entry I want to calculate the correlation of all the data up to that point so .iloc[0:current].  I'm trying to iterate through the dates. The file looks like:

```
date          price     value      
2019-08-20    ###       ###        
...           ...       ...
```

Here is my code:

```
fieldnames = ['date', 'correlation']

df = pd.read_csv(...data.csv)

with open(.../correlation.csv) as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator = '\n')
    writer.writeheader()

    for date in range(0, len(df['date'])):
        day = date
        price = df['price'].iloc[0 : date]
        value = df['value'].iloc[0 : date]
        correlation = price.corr(value)

        row = {'date' : day, 'correlation' : correlation}
        writer.writerow(row)
```

I want to put the correlation column into correlation.csv:

```
date          correlation      
2019-08-20        ###               
...               ...
```

The ilocs arent displaying anything. I'm new to python so I might be way off here but I think I might be close. Any help is GREATLY appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Is `date` an index of your dataframe ? Also, you do not want the `0` before `:`

Comment: Yes date is the index. Oh I don't need the 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `iloc` works with integer index only (based on the position), and `loc` with the value of the index.

Here are 2 suggestions:

## Example 1

```
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
fieldnames = ['date', 'correlation']

df = pd.read_csv(...data.csv)
# Set date as index
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

with open(.../correlation.csv) as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator = '\n')
    writer.writeheader()

    for date in range(0, len(df['date'])):
        day = date
        price = df['price'].loc[: date]
        value = df['value'].loc[: date]
        correlation = price.corr(value)

        row = {'date' : day, 'correlation' : correlation}
        writer.writerow(row)
```

## Example 2

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
fieldnames = ['date', 'correlation']

df = pd.read_csv(...data.csv)

with open(.../correlation.csv) as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator = '\n')
    writer.writeheader()

    for date in range(0, len(df['date'])):
        day = date
        price = df.loc[df['date'] <= date, 'price']
        value = df.loc[df['date'] <= date, 'price']
        correlation = price.corr(value)

        row = {'date' : day, 'correlation' : correlation}
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: This looks great! Thank you so much for your attention to this!